# How to control the resource of each client in NVIDIA-MPS

Tags: cuda, gpu

In nvidia-mps, we launch the mps-server by running `sudo nvidia-cuda-mps-control -d`, I have two questions.

- How to specify which GPU to run mps-server when I have multiple GPUs on the same server.
- How to control the resources (such as computation and memory) allocated for each mps client when I have multiple concurrent processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CUDA MPS doc will answer many questions like this.

> How to specify which GPU to run mps-server when I have multiple GPUs on the same server.

From the [CUDA MPS doc](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/pdf/CUDA_Multi_Process_Service_Overview.pdf), section 2.3.4, the GPUs that are [visible](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars) (via `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`) when the MPS server is started, will determine which GPUs it will use:

```
2.3.4. MPS on Multi-GPU Systems
The MPS server supports using multiple GPUs. On systems with more than one GPU,
you can use CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES to enumerate the GPUs you would like to use.
See section 4.2 for more details.
```

> How to control the resources (such as computation and memory) allocated for each mps client when I have multiple concurrent processes?

From the same doc, section 2.3.5.2, the primary method for computation allocation per process is via the setting of the environment variable `CUDA_MPS_ACTIVE_THREAD_PERCENTAGE`.  The setting of this environment variable when the process begins and initializes the CUDA runtime or driver API will determine its available compute resources (SMs) expressed as a percentage.  If you have multiple GPUs, it will be the percentage of the SM resources on the GPU selected by your application using `cudaSetDevice()` or similar.

<s>MPS doesn't provide a mechanism for per-process memory allocation/partitioning, at this time.</s>

EDIT: Update - CUDA 11.5 made publicly available on October 20th, 2021 adds a [new feature](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/mps/index.html#topic_3_3_5_4) allowing per-client memory limits in MPS.